# How to convert the timestamp from 24 hr format to 12 hr format in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert to timestamp in 24hrs fromat to 12 hrs format.Here is my code with output mentioned in braces.

```
 date = Dyear + "" + Dmonth + "" + Dday + " " + strhour+""+strminute+""+"00"; (20130628 142900)
DateTime dt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(Dyear), Convert.ToInt32(Dmonth), Convert.ToInt32(Dday), Convert.ToInt32(strhour), Convert.ToInt32(strminute), 00);(6/28/2013 2:29:00 PM)
TimeSpan ts = dt.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00));(15884.14:29:00)
String sTimeStamp = ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("0"); (1372429740000)
```

the above sTimeStamp will be in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:ttt format(06/28/2013 19:59:000) like "1372429740".
                        I want to display the time stamp in 12 hr format like MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ttt format(06/28/2013 07:59:000) like "1372386540"

Comment: But that's not the same timestamp at all... I'm finding it very hard to understand what you're really trying to achieve here. If you just want to change the timestamp to be in the morning, do that - the text format part is irrelevant.

Comment: i want to display the stock chart in 12 hrs format. so in this code i will get the timespan for the particular date and converting the date in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that the format you refer is just for displaying purposes. If you want to account for this modification in your calculations (putting 2 instead of 14), a 12h lag would appear.

If you just want to display 6/28/2013 2:29:00, you can use the following string (the calculated miliseconds will not be affected):

```
string sTimeStamp = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

If what you want is performing this change during the time calculations (not sure about the reason for doing that), you have to modify the way in which `dt` is generated (this time, the calculated milisenconds will be affected: 12h lag with respect to the option above):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(Dyear), Convert.ToInt32(Dmonth), Convert.ToInt32(Dday), Convert.ToInt32(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, Convert.ToInt32(strhour), 0, 0).ToString("hh:mm tt").Split(':')[0]), Convert.ToInt32(strminute), 0);
```

In this second case, `dt` will always be formed on account of the "12h understanding" of the input value; for example: it will account for 2(am) if `strhour` is either 2 or 14.

Answer (score 0):

```
    internal static string ConvertTo_12_Format(string str)
    {
        //using system function
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string s = dt.ToString("hh:mm");


        //using logic
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int h1 = (int)str[0] - '0';
        int h2 = (int)str[1] - '0';

        string Meridien;
        int hh = h1 * 10 + h2;

        if (hh < 12)
        {
            Meridien = "AM";
        }
        else
            Meridien = "PM";

        hh %= 12;
        int c1 = (int)str[3] - '0';
        int c2 = (int)str[4] - '0';

        if (hh == 0)
        {
            sb.Append("12:");
            //18:30
            // Printing minutes and seconds 
            sb.Append(c1.ToString() + c2.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            if(hh < 10)
            {
                sb.Append("0" + hh + ":");
                sb.Append(c1.ToString() + c2.ToString());
            }else
            {
                sb.Append(hh + ":");
                sb.Append(c1.ToString() + c2.ToString());
            }
        }

        sb.Append(" "+Meridien);

        return sb.ToString();

    }
```